# Sequelize: How can I prevent virtual columns from included relation from appearing in query result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a query that looks like this:

```js
 return GroupMember.findOne({
  where: { gid: gid, member_id: uid },
  include: [
   {
    model: User,
    as: 'member',
    attributes: ['display_name'],
   },
   {
    model: Group,
    as: 'group',
    attributes: ['name'],
   }
  ]
 });
```

So, for the "member" relation, I am requesting only the 'display_name" column.  However, the User model has 3 virtual columns declared in it, and they are always present in the query result even though I asked for only 'display_name'.  How do I prevent the virtual columns from being present in the result?

Answer (score 1):

So for excluding virtual columns, you have to use the `exclude` property the `attributes` field, so the new query should be like this

```
    return GroupMember.findOne({
    where: { gid: gid, member_id: uid },
    include: [
        {
            model: User,
            as: 'member',
            attributes: { include: ['display_name'], exclude: ['virtual_columne_name1', 'virtual_columne_name2', 'virtual_columne_name3']},
        },
        {
            model: Group,
            as: 'group',
            attributes: ['name'],
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I don't think that syntax works at version 4.42.0 of sequelize, which I am using. I see this check-in: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/a6a8146c46a629c16fa7513027b5ef2b691f7d36, and I'm no github expert but I think that adds the include/exclude syntax at 5.0 beta (even though it was like 3 years ago).  For me, if attributes is an object rather than an array, I get every attribute of the User model.

Comment: Can you print the raw query which is generated from the above command? using {logging: true} with the particular query. Check out the params of the [FindAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)